# Is any information lost by converting a fully dense array to a sparse matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, sparse-matrix

Let's suppose that A is a (`scipy`) sparse matrix with tf-idf values and B is a (`numpy`) array with some additional features of my data.

Each of the rows of `A` and `B` correspond to the same observation.

I want to concatenate these matrices/arrays because then I want to pass them to a sklearn ML model to train it and I do not think that I can pass them separately.

According, to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49420566/9024698) there are two ways to concatenate these arrays:

1. Convert the sparse array (`A`) to a dense array and then concatenate
2. Convert the fully dense array (`B`) to a sparse matrix

However, (1) in my case is basically impossible because `A` in my case is too big.

Therefore, I can think of converting my fully dense array (`B`) to a sparse array.

However, my question is do I lose any information by doing this (i.e. by converting a fully dense array to a sparse one)?

This post ([How to combine TFIDF features with other features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48573174/how-to-combine-tfidf-features-with-other-features)) is related to my post but it does not explicitly give an answer to my question.

Comment: Nope, sparse storage is not lossy. You can verify that yourself by creating a sparse matrix from your dense array, converting back (using `.A` or `.todense()` attribute) and comparing to the original array.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, ok so you mean that in the case of Adense -> Asparse -> Adense_again then Adense and Adense_again are absolutely the same?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can even directly compare `Adense==Asparse` and you will get a (dense) array filled with `True`s.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, ok sounds pretty good, thank you. Although I am not sure if this sparse representation makes any (considerable) difference to my ML model.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't lose any information. Sparse/Dense are two different representation of the same data in this case. See https://machinelearningmastery.com/sparse-matrices-for-machine-learning/ for more details